# speed of methods for building multiple list (comprehensions or not?)

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to find the most efficient way to build two separate lists with an if condition to evaluate a boolean value returned from a function.

The trunc_keys list contains have no more than 15 string elements. Test was run with 10 elements.

Common Function:

```
def is_trunc(key):
      # about 10 lines of string manipulation that ultimately returns boolean
```

**Method 1:**

```
trunc_key_list = [key for key in trunc_keys if is_trunc(key)]
bad_key_list = [key for key in trunc_keys if not is_trunc(key)]
```

**Method 2:**

```
trunc_key_list = []
bad_key_list = []

[trunc_key_list.append(key) if is_trunc(key) else bad_key_list.append(key) for key in trunc_keys]
```

I timed the results using `start_time = time.time()` and `print("%s" % (time.time() - start_time))`

**Results** (average of 20 runs)

> *Method 1*: 0.000411
>   *Method 2*: 0.000280

I expected Method 1 to be faster. I thought list comprehensions were ideal  for this type of situation by avoiding having to instantiate empty lists. I found this thread which seems to support this result:
[Python list() vs list comprehension building speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356846/python-list-vs-list-comprehension-building-speed)

I am fairly new to python and would like to understand this better. Do list comprehensions not become advantageous with such a small list size? Am I missing something else?

I appreciate any insights, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you notice we can count the number of time each statement is executed:

Let L be the length of the list

- Method 1 times ran

  - `is_trunc(key)` - ran L * 2
  - `append(key)`   - ran L * 0
- Method 2 times ran

  - `is_trunc(key)` - ran L * 1
  - `append(key)`   - ran L * 1

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216962/python-concatenation-vs-append-speed-on-lists) we can see that the average time for append is:

`~115 μs or 0.000115 seconds`

- Method 1's (single loop) total time without append: `0.000411 / 2 = 0.0002055`
- Method 2's total time without append: `0.000280 - 0.000115 = 0.000165`

We can then subtract Method 1's total time and Method 2's total time to get:

- loop time difference: `0.0002055 - 0.000165 = 0.0000405`
- total loop time difference: `0.0000405 * 2 = 0.000081`

*0.000081* is basically negligible. So the loops run nearly exactly the same speed but in the first method you iterate over the list twice so it takes twice as long.

**Take Away:** `is_trunc(key)` is expensive! What are you doing in there?? :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sense that iterating twice is slower. I did not mention this, but I prefer to have a list not exist then have a list be empty (for later checks in the code). I will prioritize speed though and just add that additional check later. Thanks.