# Adding values from list in Python to make total values based on key

Tags: python, arrays, json, algorithm, object

I'm currently struggling a lot with a specific piece of code I'm writing in Python.

I'd need to get the total values of seperate objects values, based on the same key.

Here is the JSON data I'm currently getting

```
[{
        "name": "John",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Euro",
                "amount": 100.00
            },
            {
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 223
            },
            {
                "currency": "Yen",
                "amount": 800
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 32
            },
            {
                "currency": "Euro",
                "amount": 80
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Elise",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 12
            },
            {
                "currency": "Yen",
                "amount": 66
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But! In this array of objects I would also like to add another object which contains information about the total values of each currency. I've been struggling with this for quite a bit, I've tried nested for loops but it feels like that is a waste of time and that there must be faster ways...

Anybody that can help me get the output I'm looking for?

Wanted output =

```
[{
        "name": "Total",
        "data": [{
            "Euro": {
                "amount": 180
            },
            "Dollar": {
                "amount": 267
            },
            "Yen": {
                "amount": 866
            }
        }]
    },



    {
        "name": "John",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Euro",
                "amount": 100.00
            },
            {
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 223
            },
            {
                "currency": "Yen",
                "amount": 800
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 32
            },
            {
                "currency": "Euro",
                "amount": 80
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Elise",
        "data": [{
                "currency": "Dollar",
                "amount": 12
            },
            {
                "currency": "Yen",
                "amount": 66
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your `data` for each person sometimes has `currency` and sometimes `asset_id`. Is there any consistency? Are they to be interpreted as the same thing?

Comment: Hey! Sorry that was a mistake, it's all currency!

Comment: Hello @PranavHosangadi. I've been trying for hours to get this piece of code but it hasn't worked out so sorry but I can't provide a piece of working code for the 'Total' part.

Comment: Are you sure the format of `data` in `Total` is correct? It's different from the other entries (and could be replaced by a much simpler structure, i.e., a dictionary with `{'currency': float}` entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list is called `s`, try this:

```
total = dict()
for d in s:
    for ccy in d["data"]:
        if ccy["currency"] in total:
            total[ccy["currency"]]["amount"] += ccy["amount"]
        else:
            total[ccy["currency"]] = {"amount": ccy["amount"]}
>>> total
'Euro': {'amount': 180.0}, 'Dollar': {'amount': 267}, 'Yen': {'amount': 866}}
```

If you want to combine both into a single list after, you can do:

```
s = [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}] + s
>>> s
[{'name': 'Total',
  'data': [{'Euro': {'amount': 180.0},
            'Dollar': {'amount': 267},
            'Yen': {'amount': 866}}]},
 {'name': 'John',
  'data': [{'currency': 'Euro', 'amount': 100.0},
           {'currency': 'Dollar', 'amount': 223},
           {'currency': 'Yen', 'amount': 800}]},
 {'name': 'Jack',
  'data': [{'currency': 'Dollar', 'amount': 32},
           {'currency': 'Euro', 'amount': 80}]},
 {'name': 'Elise',
  'data': [{'currency': 'Dollar', 'amount': 12},
           {'currency': 'Yen', 'amount': 66}]}]
```

Comment: The preferred way to add items to a list is `s.append(item)` (it's more Pythonic + much faster).

Comment: @fsimonjetz - You're wrong. List comprehension is *much* faster than `append`

Comment: sorry, I'm talking about `s = [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}] + s`, you're certainly right about list comprehension!

Comment: `%timeit [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}] + s`
275 ns ± 5.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Comment: `%timeit [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}].append(s)`
328 ns ± 25.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Comment: @fsimonjetz - Again, the `+` is much faster than `append`

Comment: Sorry, thank you for taking the time to reply and I'm not an expert regarding algorithm complexity, but you might be right only for a single element. As the concatenation copies the whole thing, it's supposed to be O(n^2) whereas `append` only ever puts a new element at the end of the list, hence it's O(n) worst case. Cf. [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-append-in-python/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216962/python-concatenation-vs-append-speed-on-lists), e.g. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @not_speshal Ok, I think the problem is that you didn't reassign to a variable in `%timeit [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}] + s`. Try `timeit('data.append(value)', 'data = list(range(100)); value = 20')` vs. `timeit('x = [value] + data', 'data = list(range(100)); value = 20')` - `append` *is* faster!

Comment: Please test it for OP's specific example before posting here. His `list` only has one element whereas yours has 100. `%timeit 's = [{"name": "Total", "data": [total]}] + s'` gives me 15.3 ns ± 0.817 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each). Also, this is a completely separate discussion which you can test on your own time and has nothing to do with OP's question.